# When using React Select with Menu Item, the menu is rendering horizontally rather than vertically how can I fix this?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make a dropdown menu in React and have used Select and Menu Item. However, the options in the drop down menu are rendering horizontally rather than vertically. I am not sure how to fix this and have attached my code below.

```
<div style = {{ display: 'flex', width: '500px', margin: '20px' }}>
            <div style = {{ flex: '150px', left: "79px" }}>             
              <Select 
                id = "status-menu"
                onChange={handleStatusClick}
              >
                <MenuItem value={"Awaiting Utility"}>Awaiting Utility</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={"Terminated"}>Terminated</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={"Denied"}>Denied</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={"Completed"}>Completed</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={"Approved"}>Approved</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem value={"Awaiting AccessH2O"}>Awaiting AccessH2O</MenuItem>
              </Select>
              <h4 style = {{ fontWeight: 'normal', backgroundColor: setStatusColor(dummyData.status), width: '85%', textAlign: 'center', borderRadius: '8px' }}>{status}</h4>
            </div>
            <div style = {{ flex: '100px' }}>
              <h4 style = {{ fontWeight: 'normal' }}>{dummyData.accountId}</h4>
            </div>
            <div style = {{ flex: '100px' }}>
              <h4 style = {{ fontWeight: 'normal' }}>{dummyData.propertyAddress}</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `style = {{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}` to your `<Select>` component.

Comment: I tried that and it still didn't work.

Comment: Its worth inspecting the CSS of the DOM element that contains each item `div` and posting that here so we can help debug further.

Answer (score 0):

Got into a similar issues while using [react-dropdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dropdown).

What worked for me was just removing `display: flex` from the CSS file